# How to have records appearing alongside date values based on a start date. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, time-series

I have 2 tables, one being a date list and the other being a list of objects with a corresponding start date. I would like to join the tables such that the ID appears alongside a date from the date list given that it's start date is greater than or equal to the start date of the object.

```
 Date List      ID  StartDate           Result  
29/07/2016      1   29/07/2016          Date       ID
31/08/2016      2   29/07/2016          29/07/2016  1
30/09/2016      3   31/08/2016          29/07/2016  2
31/10/2016      4   30/09/2016          31/08/2016  1
30/11/2016      5   30/09/2016          31/08/2016  2
30/12/2016      6   30/09/2016          31/08/2016  3
31/01/2017      7   31/10/2016          30/09/2016  1
28/02/2017      8   31/10/2016          30/09/2016  2
31/03/2017                              30/09/2016  3
28/04/2017                              30/09/2016  4
31/05/2017                              30/09/2016  5
30/06/2017                              30/09/2016  6
31/07/2017                              31/10/2016  1
31/08/2017                              31/10/2016  2
29/09/2017                              31/10/2016  3
31/10/2017                              31/10/2016  4
30/11/2017                              31/10/2016  5
29/12/2017                              31/10/2016  6
31/01/2018                              31/10/2016  7
                                        31/10/2016  8
```

I am not sure how to use the join statement as I only have one reference point for the ID to join with the date list. Hence I am struggling to get it to appear on subsequent dates other than its start date.

Thanks very much

Comment: Without any details I am struggling to even understand what you are asking. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I don't understand how you can write this sentence:  "it's start date is greater than or equal to the start date of the object" and then tell us you don't know how to do the join.   Do you not know what symbols to use for "greater than or equal" in SQL?  Do you not know that you can use those symbols in a join?   Did you try?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, I would suggest posting the structure and some sample records from your data. You example is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, I was finding it difficult to articulate my question so I hoped the data below would do a better job of explaining. I tried a Right Join but I wasn't aware you could use inequality operators within a JOIN. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing magic:

```
SELECT DateList.Date, ObjectList.ID
FROM ObjectList 
  INNER JOIN DateList ON ObjectList.StartDate <= DateList.Date
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you could use inequality operators in a JOIN statement

Answer (score 0):

I post here my answer how I did understand you, but it's not clear why your result contain no dates greater than 2016...

I changed the language because your dates are in language dependent format and I did not want to rewrite them as `yyyymmdd`

```
set language [British English];

declare @DateList table(dt date);
insert into @DateList values
('29/07/2016'),               
('31/08/2016'),               
('30/09/2016'),               
('31/10/2016'),               
('30/11/2016'),               
('30/12/2016'),                
('31/01/2017'),                
('28/02/2017'),               
('31/03/2017'),                              
('28/04/2017'),                              
('31/05/2017'),                              
('30/06/2017'),                              
('31/07/2017'),                              
('31/08/2017'),                              
('29/09/2017'),                              
('31/10/2017'),                              
('30/11/2017'),                              
('29/12/2017'),                              
('31/01/2018');                              

declare @obj table ( ID int,  StartDate date);
insert into @obj values
(1,   '29/07/2016'), 
(2,   '29/07/2016'), 
(3,   '31/08/2016'), 
(4,   '30/09/2016'), 
(5,   '30/09/2016'), 
(6,   '30/09/2016'),
(7,   '31/10/2016'),
(8,   '31/10/2016');

select l.*, o.id
from @DateList l join @obj o
        on l.dt >= o.StartDate
order by 1;
```